# Showing the difference between 2 char * strings in C

Tags: c, string

I am new to C, and I am trying to figure out the best way to approach this problem. I have 2 strings that are both `char *`'s.

They have multiple \n characters within the strings themselves, and they are usually about 1000 characters in length. I want to display only single lines that are different. Typically only one character (or a relatively small number) would be different in the entire string. So I was hoping to make it so that I could display only that one changed line (the whole string from \n to \n).

I'm not asking for anybody to write the code, or even supply code examples, just in theory what would be the most efficient way to do this?

I've been looking into using strtok, using the '\n' symbol as a delimiter, and then using strcmp to compare the two strings, and if they were not equal then I could add that string to a "old_data" and "new_data" array. Would this be a bad way to do this?

Any advice would be a huge help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track: `strsep` will let you chunk the string up by newline. One thing to keep in mind is that it operates on the original string in place, and doesn't allocate any new memory, which can be both a blessing and a curse.

Probably the most memory efficient way to do this would be to look into allocating arrays of pointers to hold your "old_data" and "new_data" values, and then just save the pointers that point directly into the original string rather than copying the strings themselves over. As long as your original two strings are going to stick around/not get freed from under you, this could save you a decent chunk of memory.

If you aren't ever going to be removing strings from the arrays, one naïve (but effective) way to implement your arrays is to maintain two state variables — a count, and a capacity — and double the capacity each time you're about to overflow the array. E.g.:

```
char **strArray = NULL;
unsigned int capacity = 10;
unsigned int count = 0;

strArray = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char *));

/* on insert */
if (count == capacity)
{
    capacity *= 2;
    strArray = realloc(strArray, capacity * sizeof(char *));
}

strArray[count++] = pointerIntoOriginalString;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

strtok() is not reentrant. If you were going to do this with strtok, you'd have to iterate over the arrays one after the other. I recommend using strtok_r(), which is the reentrant implementation of strtok.

The other consideration you need to worry about is making sure that your old_data and new_data arrays are big enough, or resizable. Matt's answer shows a simple example of resizing the array, although if you're new to C you might just want to declare something like:

```
char *new_data[2000];
char *old_data[2000];
```

Especially since it sounds like you have a good idea of how many lines are in your buffer.

Comment: I see, great points, thx for the input. The strtok_r() function looks like it maybe useful.